# How to create a for loop which returns an array of new date objects for remaining days in a month using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, for-loop

I need to return an array containing a Date object for each day remaining in the month, for a given Date.

I need a `for` loop that creates `new Date()` objects set to each day remaining in the month, adding them to an array and returning the array.

I came up with the code to retrieve the remaining days in the month, however I can't figure the loop / array part out for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
function findDays(theDate) {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = now.getDate();
  var last = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
  return last - date;
}

console.log(findDays() - (new Date(2016, 0, 1)).getDate());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getTime` and `setTime` methods of the Date object to advance one day at a time.

```
var days = [];
var now = new Date();
var day = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
while (day.getMonth() === now.getMonth()) {
  days.push(day);

  // Go to the next day
  day = new Date(day.getTime() + 86400000);  // There are 86400000 milliseconds in a day
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. do you have an idea of how to use this to return an array of dates with current date and last day of the month?

Comment: I have edited my answer to build an array.  I have also removed the time component from the dates,

Comment: You shouldn't just add 8.64e7 seconds to add a day since not all days are 24 hours long. *day* is initially set to 00:00:00, so on the day going out of daylight saving the new date will be 23:00 on the same day. Add 1 day instead: `day = new Date(day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1))`. That works because the *setDate* method returns the time value of the updated date.